# Formula from string

Tags: string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a string in a cell in Google Sheets that I build (that's why it is a string)

```
index(split(D9,"/"),1)
```

Now i need to turn this as a real formula - the opposite of `formulatext()`

something like TextToFormula() !

I usually use the `indirect` function, but when including a formula, it does not work

Any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: if you post about what the real problem is that you're trying to address with this solution, it might be easier to show you a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function to convert a text into a spreadsheet formula. If you are open to use an script, you migth use the setFormula method.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Related

- [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16303680/1595451)
- [Convert a text string to a formula in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35022815/1595451)
- [Convert a string to a formula in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59701209/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

you may use script which turns texted formula into real formula:

```
function onEdit() { 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Master Sheet');  //sheet name
var src = sheet.getRange("A1");    // The cell which holds the formula
var str = src.getValue();  
var cell = sheet.getRange("C5");   // The cell where I want the results to be
cell.setFormula(str);              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to transform the string into a formula, you should use the [`setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) function from Apps Script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var formula = sheet.getRange("RANGE_FOR_THE_STRING").getValue();
sheet.getRange("RANGE_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_SET_THE_FORMULA").setFormula("="+formula);
```

Depending on the structure of your string, you might need to some tweaking in order to transform it into an accurate formula, hence the `=` added in the code above.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Class Range - setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula).

Answer (score 0):

Since the addition of LAMBDA this is possible without GAS. I have created an example sheet here: [INDIRECT with ARRAYFORMULA Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vNugmEdK_9MN_xJS0H2EF92htKx4kimQkpWR7g2WOX0/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).