# Use a master formula Google sheet that other 30 sheets can connect to and use said formulas

Tags: function, google-sheets

I have made a Google sheet at work that suggests a grade (A,B,C,D or F) depending on what dropdown values have been selected, this all is working fine.

However, I am interested in knowing how I use a master Formula sheet that other sheets can connect to.

The reason I wish to do this is that each employee (around 30) uses their own sheet that all looks the same but is tied to them. This means any change in code I make, I then have to replicate across 30 or so sheets which can get time consuming and laborious.

So I would like to add my formulas to a master sheet that all the other sheets are connected to, thus allowing for a single update of the code on the master sheet and these changes are then done on the other 30 sheets.

I have a simple formula here =if(D3="F", "Scrap","") that is on my master sheet but when I attempt to take that code onto the other sheets all I get is a string and do not recognize it as a formula.

I hope this makes sense, I did do a search on this before posting this but I could not find anything, apologies if I missed it.

Thanks

I have tried referencing the formula from the other sheets but the formula comes back as a string and is not recognized as a formula. I removed the "=" sign from the formula and concatenated it back on the single sheet but even with the "=" added, it still sees it as plain text not a formula.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a script to inject the formula on the right spots or without scripts you can use Data validation and store the formula as a text string:

```
="=IF(D3=""F"", ""Scrap"", )"
```

and then deploy it as a dropdown item:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, by using the conditional formatting I would still have to go over the 30 sheets and update it manually, now the idea of a script to automatically update all those sheets in one go on a button click is intriguing. Thing is, I am a little clueless how to go about doing this, would you know how to do this? Thanks again for your comment

Comment: @neildvdsn see maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64793938/5632629

Comment: player0 - thanks for this advice but it appears to do nothing - executes fine but does not populate the cell