# Combine formulas from multiple fields to create a new formula

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, formula

There is a reason for this odd question. I am looking to combine the text from D2 and D3 into one long formula in D4. In theory =CONCATENATE("=",D2,"&", D3) would give me what I need, however google sheets does not recognize it as a formula. I cannot seem to find a solution.

**D2:**

IF(AND(Worksheet!$A2<>"",Worksheet!D2""),MID(CELL("address",D2),2,FIND("$",CELL("address",D2),2)-2)&ROW()&" cannot be blank","")

**D3:**

IFERROR(IF(MATCH(Worksheet!D2,ValidationSheet!A:A,0)>0,"",""),MID(CELL("address",D2),2,FIND("$",CELL("address",D2),2)-2)&ROW(D2)&" invalid selection")

**D4:**

(=CONCATENATE("=",D2,"&", D3) This is a working formula, but google sheets recognizes it as text and not a formula)

=IF(AND(Worksheet!$A2<>"",Worksheet!D2""),MID(CELL("address",D2),2,FIND("$",CELL("address",D2),2)-2)&ROW()&" cannot be blank","")&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(Worksheet!D2,ValidationSheet!A:A,0)>0,"",""),MID(CELL("addre s",D2),2,FIND("$",CELL("address",D2),2)-2)&ROW(D2)&" invalid selection")

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: There's a similar example here but it needs a script to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022815/convert-a-text-string-to-a-formula-in-a-spreadsheet